# How to achieve one long taskbar across two monitors in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar

I want one long taskbar across both of my monitors that has these elements on each monitor.

Monitor one: the start button, pinned applications and open windows on that monitor.

Monitor two: open windows on that monitor, links and the system tray.

Hopefully this image will help explain what I mean. I know I'm going to need some third party software, but can anyone recommend some?

[image]

Comment: We really don't make progrma suggestions, there are lots of applications like this, what sort of research have you done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this article is written for Windows XP - it will work with Windows 7. [See here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/extend-your-xp-taskbar-across-multiple-monitors-for-free/).

Comment: I have used this as well. It is a little flaky sometimes, but does achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Having used MultiMonitor Taskbar before, i switched to [Display Fusion](http://displayfusion.com/) long time ago. Have a look at the [Youtube Video](https://youtu.be/zRsnzdO8Gyk).

The only drawback is, that the free version doesn't support the multimonitor taskbar. [Comparison Free vs Pro Version](https://www.displayfusion.com/Compare/)

What i really like is, that i can choose between having ever program/window displayed on every taskbar, so the taskbars on all monitors (in my case three) show the same programs on the taskbar or you can choose to only display the programs which are currently located on this monitor, to show themself on the taskbar of this monitor.